# How To Write to a CSV with .Net in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, csv

I'm trying to use the .Net StreamWriter class to write the output of a script to a text file because the file will become quite large and .Net has proven to always be faster than native PS cmdlets. I can figure out how to write to it, but I can't figure out how to make it look like an actual spreadsheet. The closest I can get is to write each field below the previous one, and I want the fields to be side by side. I even tried writing the tab character to the file but that had no effect (which surprised me because both the new line character and return character were effective). Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When looking for help on your code, it is best practice to include an [mcve].

Comment: This is such a basic task (iterate the objects, join the properties with commas, write each line) that I'm not sure what kind of general suggestions do you expect without showing the code and data sample.

Comment: As for performance, you need to actually measure it because writing the CSV per se might not be the slowest part in your script.